# How can i get my Rails app to use my ~/.bashrc saved ENV VARS?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cmd, environment-variables, secret-key

I have saved some `ENV`'s in ~/.bashrc, go to reopen the file and i can see them there:

```
export SECRET_KEY_BASE="secretkeyhere"
export S3_SECRET_KEY="anotherhere"
export S3_ACCESS_KEY="andhere"
export DEVISE_KEY="and again"
```

Yet when i tell my rails app to use them, as for example s3 credentials in my  model with `ENV["S3_ACCESS_KEY"]` it seemingly doesn't use them, giving me the error:

```
Missing Credentials. Unable to find AWS credentials. You can configure your AWS credentials a few different ways: * Call AWS.config with :access_key_id and :secret_access_key * Export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID and AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY to ENV * On EC2 you can run instances with an IAM instance profile and credentials will be auto loaded from the instance metadata service on those instances. * Call AWS.config with :credential_provider. A credential provider should either include AWS::Core::CredentialProviders::Provider or respond to the same public methods. = Ruby on Rails In a Ruby on Rails application you may also specify your credentials in the following ways: * Via a config initializer script using any of the methods mentioned above (e.g. RAILS_ROOT/config/initializers/aws-sdk.rb). * Via a yaml configuration file located at RAILS_ROOT/config/aws.yml. This file should be formated like the default RAILS_ROOT/config/database.yml file.
```

When in shell i run `echo $DEVISE_KEY` and it returns nothing but an empty line, if i run `source ~/.bashrc` then `echo $DEVISE_KEY` it does return the key?!? So it seems it is in there somewhere, but not accessible by rails and or the right session/environment/program. As a junior to UNIX, Rails and much more I'm now at a loss as to what's happening here. Please can you help me understand what i'm doing wrong here. Thankyou.

Comment: Have you tried sourcing your bashrc file?

Comment: I've tried running `source ~/.bashrc` in a bash window and then `echo $DEVISE_KEY` will return the key. However Rails still returns the same `AWS::Errors::MissingCredentialsError in PostsController#create` error?

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative approach to handle environment variables within your application, I suggest you have a look at [`dotenv gem`](https://github.com/bkeepers/dotenv).

Instead of having to deal with ~/.bashrc files (which in your case is certainly not being loaded correctly), you can have a `.env` file in your local environment where you define the variables and that will be loaded into ENV when the environment is bootstrapped. You don't commit your `.env` file to your version control and keep it local to your environment.

In your case you'll add your variables to `.env`

```
SECRET_KEY_BASE="secretkeyhere"
S3_SECRET_KEY="anotherhere"
S3_ACCESS_KEY="andhere"
DEVISE_KEY="and again"
```

and then just call them in your AWS config file like this:

```
config.secret_key  = ENV['S3_SECRET_KEY'] 

(or whatever the config method is)
```

Hope it helps!